# Jenkins Windows slave not able to access the shared mount on Windows slave

Tags: jenkins, window, jenkins-agent

I have Jenkins master installed on Linux, i have created a  windows slave with Launch method as "Let Jenkins control this windows slave as a Windows Service".

With Run Service as 'Use Local System User', successfully connected to slave with provided credentials.

I have Windows Batch command file which access the shared mount, I'm facing "Access denied issue"

But the with same user(connected to slave), i am able to run the Batch script successfully on slave manually.